# What is the difference between rake assets:precompile and assets:precompile:all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, asset-pipeline

What's the difference between these 2 tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# from assets.rake
desc "Compile all the assets named in config.assets.precompile"
task :precompile do
  invoke_or_reboot_rake_task "assets:precompile:all"
end
```

Looks like you can omit the `:all`.